# Swift: Array of Arrays in Struct initialisation

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a struct that contains array of arrays:

```
public struct myStruct: Codable {
    var timetables:[[MyObject]] = [[]];
}
```

How to initialise the first external array so to limit by e.g. 7 and be able to insert at any index "internal" array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Array's `repeating:count:` initializer:

```
var timetable = Array(repeating: [MyObject](), count: 7)
```

Comment: Nope, when JSONdecoding if I have only one element it gives count 1

Comment: In that case you can't rely on the compiler-generated initializer anymore, but have to implement `init(from decoder: Decoder)` yourself. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Nevermind, it's me who made an error changing not in all places. Your solution perfectly works